# Segmentation Fault for numeric input

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, strtol

I'm writing my first ever program in C and it's giving me a lot of problems.
It's fairly simple; input a number and the output will be the corresponding term in the Fibonacci sequence where the first and second terms are 1. It was initially working as long as I didn't put anything other than a number as the input; letters or special characters caused a segmentation fault. To fix this, I tried to reject all non-numeric inputs, and since I couldn't find a function to do this I made my own. Unfortunately, it now gives a segmentation fault when a numeric input is given, and all non-numeric inputs are read as 26.

The compiler, gcc with pedantic warnings, only complains about my comments.
I've used GDB to narrow the segmentation fault to:

```
return strtol(c, n, 10);
```

Any help for identifying the problem and avoiding it next time would be greatly appreciated.

The Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  calcTerm(); //Run calcTerm()
  return 0; //Return value & exit
}

int fibTerm(int term)
{
  //Declare Variables
  int a = 0;
  int b = 1; 
  int next;
  int x;

  //Calculate the sequence
  for (x = 0; x <= (term - 2); x++)
  {
    next = a + b;
    a = b;
    b = next;
  }

  return next; //return the requested output
}

int calcTerm()
{
  //declare variables
  int in;
  char rawIn[256];
  char **n;
  int out;

  printf("Input the term you want to find:\n"); //request input

  //get input
  fgets(rawIn, 3, stdin);

  //define variables
  in = isNumeric(rawIn); /*strtol(rawIn, n, 10) works*/
  out = fibTerm(in);

  //print result
  printf("Term %i " "is %i", in, out);
}

int isNumeric(char test[256])
{
  //declare variables
  char validChars[10] = "0123456789"; //valid input characters
  char *c = test;
  char **n;

  if (strpbrk(test, validChars)) //if input contains only valid characters ?
  {
    return strtol(c, n, 10); //return the input as an integer
    //segmentation fault; strtol_l.c: no such file
  }
  else
  {
    printf("Please only input numbers."); //error message
  }

}
```

Comment: The program does run correctly for me

Comment: The updated code works fine for me; there are a few oddities here and there (such as the usage of ``sscanf`` in ``isNumeric`` which basically overwrites ``validChars`` with the first word of the string found in ``c``), but in general it is OK. Note that your current code evaluates the Fibonacci sequence starting from (0, 1), not from (1, 1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`n` is unitialized and it points to nowhere. `strtol` will try to write to the memory address pointed to by `n`, which could be anywhere in the memory and it is likely not pointing to an area where you are alloweed to write. Simply pass a null value there (i.e. `strtol(c, 0, 10)`).

By the way, I'd try to use `sscanf` to parse the number; `sscanf` returns the number of tokens parsed successfully, so if you get a zero as a return value, the number was invalid. E.g.:

```
const char* my_string = "  123";
const char* my_invalid_string = "spam spam spam";
int number;
sscanf(my_string, "%d", &number);    // this should return 1
sscanf(my_invalid_string, "%d", &number); // this should return 0
```

And since you are reading from the standard input anyway, you can skip storing the line in a string and then calling `sscanf`, you can simply use `scanf` to parse the standard input directly.

Comment: That fixed the segmentation fault, but now the input for 1 generates seemingly random results. Output for 1: "Term 1 is 1197354752".

Comment: ...or ask another question, posting just the section of code where the problem is occurring.

Comment: I think it's part of the calculation... An input of 1 results in x starting at 0 and increasing until it reaches -1. I should've seen that sooner.

Comment: Aaah, your're right. Simply make sure that ``next`` is not uninitialized then and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You get random output for the input `1` because in `fibTerm` the loop will never be entered (`for (x = 0; x <= (term - 2); x++)` with `term == 1`). Therefore, the uninitialized `next` value will be returned